# How to unnest and reorganize a complex nested list to run kmeans

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a list containing multiple lists of dataframes.
In the Rviewer, here is an example of what you see:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVX3W.png)

note: dataframes B-F has the same named variables.

My questions are:

1. Is there a simple way to transpose the information so that this will be one table so that:

the A:F will become character values under a new variable (e.g., "alphabet") and all of the nested variables will be combined so there aren't any duplicated variable names? For instance, List 1 would be broken up into:
(please click link for img ->)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gNif.png)

note: all of the variables would be filled, I just left it blank here.

I'm trying to do this to run kmeans specifically on three variables, bm1, bm2, and ls which are in the sample code below.

2. And after doing this, is there a simple way to revert it back to its original structure with some additional variables (e.g., clusters)?

Here is the `dput(data)` for the example code:

```
list(A = structure(list(r = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), x = c(4300, 
4800, 5300, 4300, 4800, 5300), y = c(4400, 4400, 4400, 4800, 
4800, 4800), fm1 = c(3800, 4400, 5000, 3600, 4200, 5200), fm2 = 
c(3900, 
4600, 5300, 3900, 4400, 5600), bm1 = c(400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 
400), bm2 = c(300, 300, 400, 300, 300, 400), ns = c(3600, 4200, 
4900, 3600, 4100, 5200), sn = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ls = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fa = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sln = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"), B = 
structure(list(
r = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), x = c(4300, 4800, 5300, 4300, 4800, 
5300), y = c(4500, 4500, 4500, 4900, 4900, 4900), fm1 = c(1300, 
1400, 1500, 1100, 1200, 1200), fm2 = c(1400, 1500, 1500, 
1200, 1300, 1300), bm1 = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100), 
bm2 = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100), ns = c(1200, 1400, 
1400, 1100, 1100, 1200), sn = c(0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100), 
ls = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fa = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sln = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"), 
C = structure(list(r = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), x = c(4300, 4800, 
5300, 4300, 4800, 5300), y = c(4400, 4400, 4400, 4800, 4800, 
4800), fm1 = c(4100, 4400, 4600, 3700, 4100, 3900), fm2 = c(4400, 
4600, 4900, 4000, 4400, 4300), bm1 = c(200, 200, 200, 200, 
200, 200), bm2 = c(200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200), ns = c(4200, 
4500, 4700, 3800, 4200, 4100), sn = c(0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 
200), ls = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fa = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
sln = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = 
"data.frame"), 
D = structure(list(r = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), x = c(4400, 4900, 
5400, 4400, 4900, 5400), y = c(4500, 4500, 4500, 4900, 4900, 
4900), fm1 = c(3000, 3200, 3300, 2500, 2600, 2600), fm2 = c(3400, 
3600, 3600, 2700, 2900, 2900), bm1 = c(300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 200), bm2 = c(300, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200), ns = c(3100, 
3400, 3400, 2500, 2700, 2700), sn = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
ls = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fa = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sln = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"), 
E = structure(list(r = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), x = c(4400, 4900, 
5400, 4400, 4900, 5400), y = c(4500, 4500, 4500, 4900, 4900, 
4900), fm1 = c(2500, 2300, 2400, 2700, 2400, 2300), fm2 = c(2600, 
2400, 2600, 2900, 2600, 2500), bm1 = c(200, 200, 200, 200, 
200, 200), bm2 = c(200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200), ns = c(2400, 
2200, 2400, 2700, 2400, 2300), sn = c(0, 100, 100, 0, 100, 
100), ls = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fa = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
sln = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = 
"data.frame"), 
F = structure(list(r = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), x = c(4300, 4800, 
5300, 4300, 4800, 5300), y = c(4400, 4400, 4400, 4800, 4800, 
4800), fm1 = c(3300, 3500, 3400, 2700, 3100, 3100), fm2 = c(3500, 
3700, 3700, 2900, 3300, 3400), bm1 = c(200, 200, 200, 200, 
200, 200), bm2 = c(200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200), ns = c(3300, 
3600, 3500, 2700, 3100, 3200), sn = c(0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 
0), ls = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fa = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sln = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: please post your actual data, or a small example using `dput(data)`, not a screenshot.

Comment: Unfortunately, my actual data is very large. Running dput(data) crashed my R session. I'll try to post an example code in a little bit.

Comment: post a subset if the whole data is too large

Comment: Thank you, will do

Comment: @Mike, I've updated my question with the sample code

Comment: @DaveArmstrong ,how would you approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it as simple as this:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- lapply(dat, function(x){
  tmp <- x %>% select(where(is.numeric))
  k <- kmeans(tmp, centers=2)
  x$cluster <- k$cluster
  x
})
dat
#> $A
#>   r    x    y  fm1  fm2 bm1 bm2   ns sn ls fa sln cluster
#> 1 0 4300 4400 3800 3900 400 300 3600  0  0  0   0       1
#> 2 0 4800 4400 4400 4600 400 300 4200  0  0  0   0       1
#> 3 0 5300 4400 5000 5300 400 400 4900  0  0  0   0       2
#> 4 0 4300 4800 3600 3900 400 300 3600  0  0  0   0       1
#> 5 0 4800 4800 4200 4400 400 300 4100  0  0  0   0       1
#> 6 0 5300 4800 5200 5600 400 400 5200  0  0  0   0       2
#> 
#> $B
#>   r    x    y  fm1  fm2 bm1 bm2   ns  sn ls fa sln cluster
#> 1 0 4300 4500 1300 1400 100 100 1200   0  0  0   0       1
#> 2 0 4800 4500 1400 1500 100 100 1400   0  0  0   0       2
#> 3 0 5300 4500 1500 1500 100 100 1400 100  0  0   0       2
#> 4 0 4300 4900 1100 1200 100 100 1100 100  0  0   0       1
#> 5 0 4800 4900 1200 1300 100 100 1100   0  0  0   0       1
#> 6 0 5300 4900 1200 1300 100 100 1200 100  0  0   0       2
#> 
#> $C
#>   r    x    y  fm1  fm2 bm1 bm2   ns  sn ls fa sln cluster
#> 1 0 4300 4400 4100 4400 200 200 4200   0  0  0   0       2
#> 2 0 4800 4400 4400 4600 200 200 4500 100  0  0   0       1
#> 3 0 5300 4400 4600 4900 200 200 4700 100  0  0   0       1
#> 4 0 4300 4800 3700 4000 200 200 3800   0  0  0   0       2
#> 5 0 4800 4800 4100 4400 200 200 4200   0  0  0   0       2
#> 6 0 5300 4800 3900 4300 200 200 4100 200  0  0   0       2
#> 
#> $D
#>   r    x    y  fm1  fm2 bm1 bm2   ns sn ls fa sln cluster
#> 1 0 4400 4500 3000 3400 300 300 3100  0  0  0   0       1
#> 2 0 4900 4500 3200 3600 300 200 3400  0  0  0   0       1
#> 3 0 5400 4500 3300 3600 300 200 3400  0  0  0   0       1
#> 4 0 4400 4900 2500 2700 300 200 2500  0  0  0   0       2
#> 5 0 4900 4900 2600 2900 300 200 2700  0  0  0   0       2
#> 6 0 5400 4900 2600 2900 200 200 2700  0  0  0   0       2
#> 
#> $E
#>   r    x    y  fm1  fm2 bm1 bm2   ns  sn ls fa sln cluster
#> 1 0 4400 4500 2500 2600 200 200 2400   0  0  0   0       1
#> 2 0 4900 4500 2300 2400 200 200 2200 100  0  0   0       2
#> 3 0 5400 4500 2400 2600 200 200 2400 100  0  0   0       2
#> 4 0 4400 4900 2700 2900 200 200 2700   0  0  0   0       1
#> 5 0 4900 4900 2400 2600 200 200 2400 100  0  0   0       2
#> 6 0 5400 4900 2300 2500 200 200 2300 100  0  0   0       2
#> 
#> $F
#>   r    x    y  fm1  fm2 bm1 bm2   ns  sn ls fa sln cluster
#> 1 0 4300 4400 3300 3500 200 200 3300   0  0  0   0       1
#> 2 0 4800 4400 3500 3700 200 200 3600 100  0  0   0       2
#> 3 0 5300 4400 3400 3700 200 200 3500 100  0  0   0       2
#> 4 0 4300 4800 2700 2900 200 200 2700   0  0  0   0       1
#> 5 0 4800 4800 3100 3300 200 200 3100   0  0  0   0       1
#> 6 0 5300 4800 3100 3400 200 200 3200   0  0  0   0       2
```

This code will put all the data together with the appropriate identifier for which dataset it comes from:

```r
dat <- lapply(1:length(dat), function(i){
  x <- dat[[i]]
  x$alphabet <- names(dat)[i]
  x
})

all_dat <- dplyr::bind_rows(dat)
```

Comment: Thank you, Dave. My main goal is try to run kmeans on my list of dataframes. If there's a simpler way of doing this, I would greatly appreciate your help

Comment: @codable I updated the answer with a shot at what you're looking for.  If you want to do `kmeans()` on each dataset separately, this does it, I think.

Comment: Dave, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! I spent hours trying to solve this yesterday and today. I would vote up your answer, but unfortunately, I'm still new here so I don't have enough reputation points. I had a follow-up question if you don't mind me asking. My original data contains other non-numeric and non-integer classes, so I've only subsetted the numeric and non-integer classes. Is there a way to add the cluster variable back to the original list? Also, is there a way to apply kmeans  across each dataframes (e.g., comparing A-F)?

Comment: The first question can be done easily, I'll update the answer.  What do you mean by " apply kmeans across each dataframes (e.g., comparing A-F)"?

Comment: Thank you. What I mean is that I'm trying to see whether A-F would fall into clusters themselves after comparing their bm1 and bm2. E.g.,  would A and C become 1 cluster, B and D become a second cluster, and E and F become a third cluster?

Comment: And Dave, I am getting this error after running the updated code: Warning in storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1). Would you do something like selecting a non-character class?

Comment: @codable The updated code worked for me even when I had factor and character variables included, so I'm not sure what the problem would be.  As for your other question, do you just want to put all the data together and do a single cluster analysis?  I'm not sure what you mean by "after comparing their bm1 and bm2".  I know they are variables in the data, but I don't know what you mean by "after comparing".

Comment: @codable I suspect you know a lot more about the analyses you want to run than I do.  I added a snippet to the end of my answer that would put all the data together in a single data frame with the appropriate identifier for which list element the observation came from.

Comment: Thank you, Dave, I appreciate it all your help. One last question, if you don't mind me asking. I think the error message comes from some of my nested variables being of a "double" class type or that one of my nested variables is another list of a "double" class. Would you have any advice to work around this?

Comment: If you've got nested lists, or something like that, you'd probably need to unnest them first.

Comment: I think I figured it out. The issue was with the nested variable being another list. My solution was to to subset the variables that I need and run kmeans. Then, rbind the results back to the original list. Thank you once again for all your help, Dave! Your kindness really inspired me. As you've helped me, I'll help others on this forum.